# How do I disable livereload from the Gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, heroku, server

I have my angularjs deployed on heroku and I want to disable livereload being added into my index.html as it keep pending on my request and it makes my site goes so slow.

my Gruntfile looks like this.

```
'use strict';
  module.exports = function (grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);


  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  grunt.initConfig({

    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },


    connect: {
      options: {
        port: process.env.PORT || 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: '0.0.0.0', // server
        //hostname: 'localhost',//localhost
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },


    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },


    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },


    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },


    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },


    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
      }
    },


    cssmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: 'styles/*.css',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      build: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: '**/*.js',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts',
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts'
        }]
      },
      options: {
        mangle:false
      },
    },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: '**/*.html',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },


    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
         cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
          src: '**/*.js',
         dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts',
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },


    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [ '**']
        },{

          expand:true,
          cwd:'bower_components',
          dest:'<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components',
          src:['**']
        } ,

        {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
          src: 'fonts/*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },


    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


   grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'uglify',
      'clean:server',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

   grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'uglify',
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'copy:dist',
    'cssmin',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'uglify',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'uglify',
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('heroku:production', 
    'clean:dist',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'copy:dist',
    'cssmin',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'uglify',
    'htmlmin'
    );

   grunt.registerTask('heroku:development', 
    'clean:dist',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'copy:dist',
    'cssmin',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'uglify',
    'htmlmin'
    );

};
```

Since I am on production there in Heroku I dont need livereload...

Comment: normally after doing, `NODE_ENV=production grunt build:dist`, you should directly run `NODE_ENV=production node server/app.js` without using grunt.

Comment: how do I run without using of grunt? I mean I dont have any nodejs app to start or something, I just used grunt which executed grunt serve and the app used to open...

Comment: actually your grunt file has serve:dist, that shouldnt run live reload too.

Comment: I am just stuck, how do I run my AngularJS app which is deployed on Heroku without grunt, or with grunt but without livereload functionality

Comment: you can do grunt serve right? just try grunt serve:dist

Comment: @YOU  i am able to run this command locally, eventhou I keep an error aborted msg... is there any way that I can prevent liverelod being added into my index.html even when I normally run my app with 'npm start' into Heroku

Comment: what error you got? and what does npm start defined in package.json? may be you just need to change grunt serve:dist on npm start script. Also you can debug heroku with heroku logs command btw.

Comment: i did fixed it by setting livereload: false into the connect.option... and my npm start does grunt serve